# How can I set 2 values for one variable, and the component will render with one value, depending of some prop input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new here, So if my question is not good, Please let me know so that  I can edit.

I'm using ReactJS + Material UI. I have a component, but I want this component to be rendered with different properties depending on the props, like this:

In the page where I want render the component:

```
<AdBanner vertical={true} />
```

Inside my AdBanner component I have:

```
export default function AdBanner(props) {
  const [adWidth, setAdWidth] = useState("100%");
  const [adHeight, setAdHeight] = useState("90px");
  const [adSpacing, setAdSpacing] = useState(2);
  const [adDirection, setAdDirection] = useState("row");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.vertical) {
      console.log("ola");
      setAdWidth("320px");
      setAdHeight("480px");
      setAdSpacing(5);
      setAdDirection("column");
    }
  }, [props.vertical]);

  return (
    <>
      <Paper
        variant="outlined"
        sx={{ width: { xs: "100%", md: adWidth }, overflow: "hidden" }}
      >
      ...
```

My goal is, when I don't specify a value for the "vertical" property my component has certain characteristics (like height, width, ... ). But in some parts of my application I want a set of others values ​​for the same property.

I was getting some errors, with the help of #guilfer I was able to eliminate these errors.

Can anyone tell me if what I did is correct? Thanks.

Here the full code:
https://github.com/brunovjk/saude-vapor

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are some things on your code that you can't actualy do in javascript.
When a variable is defined using the "var", it has global scope.
Here is an explanation about the differences: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/var-let-and-const-whats-the-difference/

After that, there are some other things that we don't actualy do in React, usualy in your case, there would be two different classes with the style you want, then, for aplying the style you could do something similar to this:

```js
import style from "style.module.css"

export default function AdBanner(props) {

  return <div className={props.vertical? style.firstClass : style.secondClass}>banner content<div>
}
```

```css
.firstClass {
 ...one css styles
 }
 
 .secondClass {
 ...another css style
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. var, let and const still confuse me a bit, I will read the article you indicated.
Awesome, I believe this is what I was looking for, but I don't know the exact words to find in searches. I'll test it now and let you know how it went.
Thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: No worries! You can build this up over time. What I can tell you, though, is that you are missing some initial concepts and jumping through something much more complex. Try to review some initial guides on js and react, it sure will help you!

Comment: Hello again. I was not able to do as you said. I'm using Material UI and couldn't use this {props._? (_) : (_) } inside a style={{}}. I managed to do it using useState. I edited the question. Everything seems to be working. But as you said, there is still a lot of React base to learn.

Comment: You can't really use as I proposed a css module file into the style prop, if you can notice, I have used the className prop for that.
Some of these things will come naturally over time while you learn.

Comment: Awesome :) tahnk you so much. I`m doing more tests, I will edit the qestion later.

Comment: You shouldnt, really.
The question should only be edited to make it clearer, not to change its content. I won't do that, but its often seen closed questions that have been modified.